# SDL setup visual studio

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm trying to setup SDL for Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express, yet I constantly get the following errors when running a simple program

```
    #include "SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char* args[] ) {
    //Start SDL
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

And then I get the following errors

```
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Sean Kwon\Desktop\c++_programs\SDLtest\Debug\SDLtest.exe', Symbols loaded.
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SDL.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll'
'SDLtest.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'
'SDLtest.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll'
'SDLtest.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll'
'SDLtest.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'
'SDLtest.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'
'SDLtest.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'
'SDLtest.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll'
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KBDUS.DLL', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KBDUS.DLL'
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KBDUS.DLL', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KBDUS.DLL'
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dsound.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dinput.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\hid.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wintrust.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\crypt32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'SDLtest.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msasn1.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x15e4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x150c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[5584] SDLtest.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I added the .dll folder in my Syswow64 folder but I still get the same errors...

Comment: There are no fatal errors in that output.  Your application ran and returned `0`.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to output a window?

Comment: Initialize video and put a while(1) in the code.

Comment: You have no loop, the window closed instantly, refer to the SDL documentation for an example. Here's a simple one: http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/Resizable_Windows

Answer (score 1):

Your code has been executed successfully and returned 0.

"Cannot find or open the PDB file"
You can safely ignore these warnings for the large part. These warnings mean that the compiler cannot find the debug information for the listed dlls. This is for loading the symbols of external dependencies, for example, ones that the IDE links internally or the OS API uses, and are generally not required for the basic debugging in your program.

Try [these tutorials](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/index.php) or refer to the SDL documentation for more help on setting up and using SDL.

Answer (score 0):

The PDB files are not found, which means you need to get them.

Tools -> options -> Debugging -> Symbols

check 'Microsoft Symbol Server' to load the symbols you're missing.